# how to save and read a list of class object using shared preferences in Flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i have the following class :

```
class Payment {
      String date;
      String time;
      String code;
      String toPay;
      String payed;
      String left;
      Payment({ this.date, this.code, this.toPay, this.payed, this.left, this.time });
    }
```

in my Flutter App i'm supposed to save and read a list of `payments` using `shared preferences` and use the `date` attribute as the `key`

```
_ReadPayment(String date) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = date;
    // here how i get the list of payment like getPaymentList instead of getStringList
  final value = prefs.getStringList(key) ?? null;
}

_SavePayment(String date, List<Payment> list) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = date;
  // here how i set Payment list instead of setStringList
  prefs.setStringList(key,list);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the method `setListString` of the `SharedPreference` takes a List of String.

**TO SAVE**

1. Create a  method `toMap()` in your `Payment` class which convert a `Payment` object to a `Map`.

```dart
class Payment {
  String date;
  String time;
  String code;
  String toPay;
  String payed;
  String left;
  Payment({
    this.date,
    this.code,
    this.toPay,
    this.payed,
    this.left,
    this.time,
  });

  // method to convert Payment to a Map
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    'date': date,
    'time': time,
    ....// do the rest for other members
  };
}
```

2. Convert your `Payment` instance to a `Map<String, dynamic>`

```dart
 // payment instance 
 Payment payment = Payment();
 // convert the payment instance to a Map
 Map<String, dynamic> mapObject = payment.toMap();
```

3. Encode the value of the `Map<String, dynamic> gotten from the **step 1**

```dart
 // encode the Map which gives a String as a result
 String jsonObjectString = jsonEncode(mapObject);
```

4. The encoded result is a `String` which you can add to a `List` that can be passed to the `SharedPreference` `setListString` method.

```dart
  // list to store the payment objects as Strings
  List<String> paymentStringList = [];
  // add the value to your List<String>
   paymentStringList.add(jsonObjectString);
```

---

**TO READ**

1.Create a factory constructor `fromMap()` in your `Payment` class which convert a `Map` to a `Payment` object.

```dart
class Payment {
  String date;
  String time;
  String code;
  String toPay;
  String payed;
  String left;
  Payment({
    this.date,
    this.code,
    this.toPay,
    this.payed,
    this.left,
    this.time,
  });

  // factory constructor to convert Map to a Payment
  factory Payment.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => Payment(
      date: map['date'],
      time: map['time'],
      .... // other members here
    );
```

2. Get the `Json String` from the `List`

```dart
 // get the json string from the List
 String jsonObjectString = paymentStringList[2]; // using index 2 as an example
```

3. Convert the `Json String` to a `Map` by decoding it

```dart
 // convert the json string gotten to a Map object
 Map mapObject = jsonDecode(jsonObjectString);
```

4. Use the `fromMap` constructor of your `Payment` class to convert the `Map` to a `Payment` object

```dart
  // use the fromMap constructor to convert the Map to a Payment object
  Payment payment = Payment.fromMap(mapObject);
  // print the members of the payment class
  print(payment.time);
  print(payment.date);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , looks like what i need , i'll try it and tell you

Answer (score 1):

Shared preference does not support saving Dart object directly.
What you can do is serialize your object ( Payment ) into a json string (we call this map in dart) then saved it as string .

Then when you read it, you just deserialize it.

You can achieve that using a library I recommend Json serializer but you can also do that easily manually.

Give it a try and let me know how it goes in the comment.